# PowerShell ISE Script Replicating Data

Tags: shell, powershell, unix, scripting

I am running multiple scripts in PowerShell ISE to allow me to remove a specific line of code in many XML documents. The code I have been advised to use is the following:

```
Get-Content .\AdamInfTest.xml | Get-Content .\AdamInfTest.xml | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch '<!DOCTYPE'} | Set-Content .\Complete\AdamInfTestOut.xml
```

This will remove the line of code in the XML file with the text 'DOCTYPE' and this does work. However, when running the script the outputted file is replicating the entire document code over and over until the file becomes worryingly large (about 30MB when the non-scripted XML is about 60KB).

I am unsure why this is happening and any help would be appreciated - Thanks!

Comment: Use only one Get-Content

Comment: This `Get-Content .\AdamInfTest.xml | Get-Content .\AdamInfTest.xml` doesn't make sanse as this will mean that you re-read the whole `.\AdamInfTest.xml` for each line in the `.\AdamInfTest.xml` file. I guess that   60Kb times the number of lines in the `.\AdamInfTest.xml` (which I do not know) is about 30Mb... In other word what happens when you remove one of the `Get-Content .\AdamInfTest.xml`?

Comment: Thank you this has solved my problem! Not all heroes wear capes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Get-Content .\AdamInfTest.xml | Get-Content .\AdamInfTest.xml doesn't make sanse as this will mean that you re-read the whole .\AdamInfTest.xml for each line in the .\AdamInfTest.xml file. I guess that 60Kb times the number of lines in the .\AdamInfTest.xml (which I do not know) is about 30Mb... In other word what happens when you remove one of the Get-Content .\AdamInfTest.xml? –